# How can I isolate HDMI sounds to a TV while game sounds to system speaker in Win7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, hdmi

I have a desktop PC which I use to play games on AND watch films.

Its a Win 7  OS... with an ASUS EAH6450 hd gfx card with HDMI, DVI outputs.

Is there a way for me to be able to play a game on the monitor (through DVI) with just the system/game sounds coming through my system speakers while my partner watches a film on the TV through the HDMI output using Media Player Classic (with just the film soundtrack)

Sofar the only way for me to be able to play while she watches TV is to mute the gamesounds from within the game so there is no bleedthough/cross-over from the game to the TV which kind of ruins the game experience.

Comment: I tried using VLC... setting both Audio and Video to HDMI only then leaving the speakers as default, but it has no effect, either all the sounds come through the TV or through the speakers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I've had is by using a media player that supports selecting the output audio device.

Personally I use VLC, and the option still seems hidden.
In the preferences dialog, with all options enabled, it's under Audio > Output modules > DirectX.

I just keep it set to my HDMI connection and my speakers as the default audio device.

Comment: Ah VLC, I shall give that a go. I'm not very techie, so haven't looked too deep in the MPC settings, but if you can do it through VLC then I shall give that a go.

Concidering how modern pc's are now, you'd think that this would be automatic HDMI sound to one device and system/games to speakers.

Comment: Hrmm, I d/l'ed VLC, left my speakers as default audio for system sounds, I set VLC like you said to DirectX output to HDMI and hasn't worked.... its still the same. All sounds from games AND films come through the speakers. I have the TV set up as an extended desktop and just fullscreen the media player there. could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Windows will output audio to the default device automatically.  Some applications have software options to output sound to a device *other* than the default device.  A good example of this would be running a game on your computer and using Ventrilo to output other players audio to the headset.

You may be able to play with the "default communication device" settings to output to two devices at once, but Ive never tried this.

Comment: That's exactly the problem, everything goes to the default device. I have been trying to fix this issues for days now, but I'm no wizard with Win7 so I was hoping there might be a hidden option somewhere. If I plug in my headphones, all sounds goto them too, and no sounds come from the TV. I shall keep trying tho - until I give up and buy a separate pc for media only :)